# htaccess ajax call and hide html from search engine

Tags: html, ajax, .htaccess

so i developed a simple website which is using ajax call to html files to display.
the issue is that the search engine like google find the html file, and when we click on the link we see a poor html file out of context of the website of course.
so im guessing i have some work to do with htaccess file to handle this but how ?
my idea is to use htaccess rewriterule to redirect any .html file to the main index.php file.

something like that :
- www.my.com/team.html will call www.my.com/index.php which will detect the query-string team.html and will proceed to ajax loading the corresponding html file.

how is that possible please ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when we click on the link we see a poor html file out of context of the website of course."?

Answer (score 0):

Generally all search engines respect the terms set in the robots.txt file. If you wish that files in a particular folder in your site should not be crawled, the robots.txt can instruct the search engine to obey.

If you wish to lern about it, here is the link: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

You may see http://www.google.co.in/robots.txt for example.

Comment: Please improve your post to say what you wish to achieve.

Comment: sure will try. i have one file index.php which is using ajax call to load and display external html file, lets say team.html. I want the user to be able to type the url www.my.com/team.html so that the index.php file is loading instead, then it will load by ajax the team.html. Hope that clarifies. Note that i already have the javascript code handling the html ajax loading job. So i guess i just require a rewriterule in a htaccess ? thanks

Comment: You wish the user to type http://my.com/team.html and want to redirect to index.thp instead and then some AJAX will load team.html. Right? So why were you talking about search engine?

Comment: yes you right - i was talking abt search engine because this is the root of the issue, this is how we figure out this problem. thanks for your help